# Why am I seeing all ships' cargo status?

Tags: x4-foundations

I've been playing version 2.60 for a while now and my rep with most factions is quite high. One thing that I'm used to seeing on the map in green (for my ships) is their planned course and an indication of cargo status after orders are completed. For example, if my ship has 1000 energy cells on-board and I queue up orders that will only sell 450 of them, I'll see "Cargo remaining: 550 energy cells" hovering over the last waypoint.

What's strange is that now I'm seeing those same messages in blue (for friendly / allied ships). This is interesting information but it's pretty distracting and definitely clutters the display when I'm in a busy sector.

So, the question is: what changed? Did my rep get so high that I'm now privy to all the allied plans? Can I turn off those displays to reduce map clutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I was right: when your rep gets high enough with your allies, they will share their routes and cargo plans with you. This is interesting but, if you're in the middle of war planning, can be a bit distracting.

Fortunately, there's a checkbox in the display options to enable / disable allied ship plans. If you're not in the mood, turn them off!